# Нарисовать линию на игровом поле - java

Tags: java, swing

Задание: нарисовать на игровом поле линию(потом переделаю на то что нужно) при клике
Проблема: поле рисую на ура, а вот линия при клике не рисуется...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JFrame{
    public static final int n=10;
    public static void main() {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(305,330);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(){//это рисует
            Graphics2D g2;

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g2=(Graphics2D)g;

                for (int i=0;i<frame.getWidth();i=i+(frame.getWidth()-5)/n)
                {
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.drawLine(i,0, i, frame.getHeight());
                }
                for (int i=0;i<frame.getHeight();i=i+(frame.getHeight()-30)/n)
                {
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2.drawLine(0,i, frame.getWidth(),i);
                }
            }
        };
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.print(e.getX() / 30);
                System.out.println((e.getY() / 30) - 1);
                JPanel X = new JPanel(){//а вот это нет
                    Graphics2D g2;

                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        g2=(Graphics2D)g;
                            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                            g2.drawLine(100,100,200,200);
                    }
                };
                contentPane.add(X);
            }
        });
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: вызовите после `contentPane.add(X)` `contentPane.revalidate()`, чтобы программа пересчитала размеры и положение содержимого `contentPane`. Если у панели поменять фон, то вы даже увидите результат.

Comment: нууу как бы изменения есть, но....
линию не рисует...
изменение в том что затерло где-то 5мм одной полоски

Comment: ну полоска относится к игровому полю

Comment: как здесь скрин вставить?)))))

Comment: Посмотрите здесь, пожалуйста: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801734/how-to-draw-lines-in-java

Comment: Задача обязательно должна решаться на устаревшем swing'e? Если нет, возможно, Вам будет интересно познакомиться с JavaFX? (Он и 3D умеет из коробки).

Comment: это крестики-нолики..., функционал есть, нужно только визуализацию
при клике должно рисовать крестик или нолик, так вот не получается ничего нарисовать, кроме как игрового поля....